# Nothing uses /dev/sda but gives ioctl error with device mapper

Tags: linux, fedora

On Archlinux I could just setup a device mapper to the main hard drive /dev/sda.
On Fedora it won't let me and says "device-mapper: reload ioctl on ... failed, device or resource busy".
journalctl gives this - `device-mapper: table: xx:xx: linear: Device lookup failed (-EBUSY)` and then `device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table`
I looked and I am seeing nothing is using /dev/sda. I tried lsof and fuser. How do I find what's causing this error?

The goal state is simple: to have /dev/sda parent hard drive available for ad hoc ephemeral device mappings (that may even overlap existing partition layout and exist on top). This works when the entire /dev/sda is not partitioned at all and is just directly device mapped to some encrypted partitions (plain dm-crypt root fs with detached /boot).

Comment: `lsof` and `fuser` will only report about userspace uses of a device, not about in-kernel uses. Check `dmsetup ls --tree -o blkdevname` to see if `sda` is already used by another mapping.

Comment: That shows that only /dev/sda1 is used by luks for the root fs. No /dev/sda is used by another mapping.

Comment: journalctl gives this - "device-mapper: table: xx:xx: linear: Device lookup failed (-EBUSY)" and then "device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments:

Partition `sda1` is part of disk `sda`, so if your LUKS-encrypted root filesystem is on `sda1`, you won't be able to map the whole of `sda` because LUKS has already claimed exclusive access to a specific part of it (i.e. the partition `sda1`). You could map other unmounted partitions, though.

You seem to be trying to add a `linear` mapping. That might mean you could be trying to construct a JBOD out of `sda` and some other disk. In order not to invalidate the partitions on `sda`, it would have to be the first device in the linear mapping, and you would have to establish the mapping in initramfs before the root filesystem's LUKS encryption layer is activated. You might have to use `kpartx` or similar to create individual mappings on top of the JBOD for partitions existing on it, so that LUKS would have a chance to find the partition containing your encrypted root filesystem. Is this what you are trying to do?

(Instead of using comments to provide more information when asked, you should *edit your question* to add that information in. Comments will eventually expire, and if essential information to understand the situation is only in comments, the question and any answers it has received will become useless to others in the future.)

You might want to describe your desired goal state: how would you want your device mappings (including your root filesystem) be laid out when you're done? Then we could provide answers on how to best make that happen in Fedora.

Because the installation process of Arch inherently includes manual operations within chroot, it may well be more flexible to accept configurations that would be considered unusual for Fedora.

Comment: Thanks! I did not use LUKS on Arch so it may be the culprit. But what is it about LUKS that makes it claim the entire parent hard drive /dev/sda when it's only dealing with one partition /dev/sda1?? And as a sequitur, will detaching LUKS header alleviate this condition?

Comment: Your second mapping is trying to claim the entire drive but cannot do that because part of it is already mapped by a `crypt`-type mapping by LUKS. As far as I know, device-mapper does not allow two mappings to have overlapping source sides like that. Detaching the header won't have any effect on that: the end result is still a `crypt` mapping over `sda1`, and only `cryptsetup close` or equivalent `dmsetup remove` would get rid of it... and to do that, you would have to unmount your root filesystem first.

Comment: The kind of `linear` mapping of the entire `sda` you're planning would, if allowed, enable you to easily corrupt your root filesystem by mistake. Because of the encryption, you wouldn't be able to read anything useful from the area occupied by `sda1` either. But if you don't plan to do any writing, try making your `linear` mapping explicitly read-only when creating it: while conflicting writeable mappings are not allowed, read-only mappings might be.

Comment: It's weird you write this because I WAS able to do linear mapping of nonoverlapping small parts of /dev/sda when my root filesystem was also linearly mapped to /dev/sda. Isn't that the whole point of dmsetup linear? So it must be the LUKS issue, and it feels like something is wrong if LUKS would somehow prevent linear device mapping to non-used parts of /dev/sda?

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps it could be an interaction between partitioning and the device mapper... or perhaps you've miscalculated something and it's actually stopping you from making a bad mistake? Would you like to add to your question the `fdisk -l` output of your partitioning, the `dmsetup table` of your existing mappings, and the exact description of the mapping you're trying to add but failing, please? Perhaps having more pairs of eyes seeing the actual hard data might resolve the mystery.

Comment: Thanks for you help. It's okay, I think this is enough data. Maybe someone will chip in and know what's going on. I might try to narrow it down later and see if it's something that's related to Fedora or LUKS. I can manually set up device mapping linked to a second hard drive that's not automouned at boot...so I suspect it's LUKS and the way it's setup. Just wish there was some nice way to track this down.